# Is it possible to extend the ResourceFunction CombinePlots for more than two axes?

Tags: plotting

Assume there are three data and would like to plot as comment x-axis and three y-axis and present them precisely as the `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]` does for two data with two Y axes, can we extend that this function for more more than two Y axes?

```
dat1 = Table[{10.^i, Log[10.^i]}, {i, 1, 10}];
dat2 = Table[{10.^i, i Log[10.^i]}, {i, 1, 10}];
dat3 = Table[{10.^i, i Sin[i] Log[10.^i]}, {i, 1, 10}];
```

For two data we can d that like

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 450, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y1"}, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], 
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat2, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y2"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}, 
  FrameStyle -> Darker@Green, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

now, how can I add another y axis for `dat3`? and why dont `PlotMarkers` appear on the green curve?

**Update1**

the two answers by @kglr and Lukas are great, I still have one point regarding control of the `PlotRange` for each data. using @Lukas approach it gives

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat1, PlotRange -> {0, 30}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 450, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y1"}, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], 
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat2, PlotRange -> {0, 300}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y2"}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]},
   FrameStyle -> Darker@Green, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], 
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat3, PlotRange -> {-200, 200}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y3"}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]},
   FrameStyle -> Orange, PlotStyle -> Orange, Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], 
 "AxesSides" -> {Left, Right, Right -> 2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Update 3:** A poor-mans-combinePlots adding sub-options that we wish `MultiaxisArrangement` could handle out-of-the box

```
ClearAll[wishTheseMultiaxisOptionsWorked]

wishTheseMultiaxisOptionsWorked[o : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{RL = RotateLeft,
   lbls = "$axisLabels" /. {o}, 
   pr = "$plotRanges" /. {o}, 
   lpos = "$labelPositions" /. {o},
   apos = "$axisPositions" /. {o}, 
   xtl = "$xtickLengths" /. {o},
   ytl = "$ytickLengths" /. {o}}, 
  If[lbls === "$axisLabels", Identity, 
    ReplaceAll[
     {{AxisObject[{d_, p_, r_}, r2_, opts___], {{dir___, _Line}}} :> 
        AxisObject[{d, 
          If[apos === "$axisPositions", p, Last[apos = RL[apos]]], r}, r2,
         BaseStyle -> dir,
         AxisLabel -> Placed[Last[lbls = RL[lbls]],
          If[ lpos === "$labelPositions", {1.05, {0, .5}}, 
            Last[lpos = RL[lpos]]]], 
         TickLengths -> If[ytl === "$ytickLengths", {.035, .015}, ytl],
         LabelStyle -> dir, opts],
      AxisObject[dr : {"Horizontal", ___}, x_, y___] :>
        AxisObject[dr, x,
         TickLengths -> 
           If[ xtl === "$xtickLengths", {.035, .015}, xtl], y]} ]]@*
   If[pr === "$plotRanges", Identity,
    ReplaceAll[
     {Inset[i_, p___] :>
       Inset[Show[i, PlotRange -> {First@PlotRange[i], Last[pr = RL[pr]]}], p],
     AxisObject[aa : {"Vertical", __}, b_, c___] :>
       AxisObject[aa, Thread[b[[All, 1]] -> Last[pr = RL[pr]]], c]} ]]]
```

***Examples:***

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{dat1, dat2, dat3}, PlotStyle -> plotStyles, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Linear"}, Mesh -> All, 
  LabelStyle -> 16, ImageSize -> Large, 
  MultiaxisArrangement -> {Left -> 1, Right -> {2, 3}}]
```

[image]

```
wishTheseMultiaxisOptionsWorked["$axisLabels" -> {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3"}] @ llp
```

[image]

```
wishTheseMultiaxisOptionsWorked[
  "$axisLabels" -> {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3"}, 
  "$plotRanges" -> {{0, 40}, {0, 300}, {-200, 200}}] @ llp
```

[image]

```
wishTheseMultiaxisOptionsWorked[
  "$labelPositions" -> {{0.5, {0.5, -2}}, {0.5, {0.5, 3}}, {0.5, {0.5, 3}}},
  "$axisLabels" -> {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3"}, 
  "$plotRanges" -> {{0, 40}, {0, 300}, {-200, 200}}, 
  "$axisPositions" -> {0, 1, Offset[80, 1]}] @ llp
```

[image]

**Update 1:** The option [`MultiaxisArrangement`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultiaxisArrangement.html) gives most of what we need. It does not work with `ListLogLinearPlot` so we use `ListLinePlot` and use `ScalingFunctions` to get the desired scaling:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[{dat1, dat2, dat3}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Darker@Green, Orange}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Linear"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}, 
  MultiaxisArrangement -> {Right -> {2, 3}, Left -> {1}}, 
  LabelStyle -> 16, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

We post-process to make the desired changes in styling and labeling:

```
labels = "Y" <> ToString[#] & /@ {1, 2, 3};

llp2 = llp /. 
  {{a_AxisObject, {{dir___, _Line}}} :> 
     Insert[a, {BaseStyle -> dir, 
       AxisLabel -> Placed[Last[labels = RotateLeft[labels]], {1.05, {0, .5}}], 
       TickLengths -> {.035, .015}, LabelStyle -> dir}, 3], 
    AxisObject[a : {"Horizontal", ___}, b_, c___] :> 
       AxisObject[a, b, TickLengths -> {.035, .015}, c]}
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Post-process to modify the plot ranges of individual plots:

```
pranges = {{0, 30}, {0, 300}, {-200, 200}};

llp2 /. {Inset[i_, p___] :> 
   Inset[Show[i, PlotRange -> {First@PlotRange[i], 
       Last[pranges = RotateLeft[pranges]]}], p], 
  AxisObject[a : {"Vertical", __}, b_, c___] :> 
   AxisObject[a, Thread[b[[All, 1]] -> Last[pranges = RotateLeft[pranges]]], c]}
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

Looks like [`ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots) does not support more than 2 axes in each direction. (As of this Q/A it DOES -- see [this answer by Lukas Lang](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/284347/125))

A work-around is to use [`AxisObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AxisObject.html) to create a custom axis object and place it as `Epilog`:

```
combinePlots = ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"];

options = {PlotRangePadding -> 0, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 450, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}}; 

{lp1, p2, lp3} = MapThread[ListLogLinearPlot[#, FrameLabel -> {"X", #3}, 
      FrameStyle -> #2, PlotStyle -> #2, options] &] @
  {{dat1, dat2, dat3}, {Blue, Darker@Green, Orange}, {"Y1", "Y2", "Y3"}};
```

First, we can nest `combinePlot` to get all three plots appropriately scaled in a single plot:

```
lp123 = combinePlots[lp1, 
   combinePlots[lp2, lp3, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"], 
   "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"]
```

[image]

Next, we extract the vertical plot range of `lp123` to be used in specifying the axis range in `AxisObject`:

```
vrange = Last @ PlotRange @ lp123;

hpos = 1.15;

y3Axis = AxisObject[{"Vertical", Scaled[hpos], vrange}, 
   Last @ PlotRange @ lp3, 
   TickPositions -> {6, 6}, TickLengths -> {0.75, .4}, 
   TickDirection -> Up, BaseStyle -> Orange, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[16, Orange], 
   AxisLabel -> Placed["Y3", {.5, {0.5, 3.}}], RotateLabel -> 90 °];
```

Use `y3Axis` as [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) in `combinePlots`:

```
combinePlots[lp1, combinePlots[lp2, lp3, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY", 
 Epilog -> y3Axis,  
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Scaled[.18]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> 700, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],]
```

[image]

To verify that the new axis ticks are correctly positioned, reverse the positions of `lp2` and `lp3` in the inner `combinePlot` and make ticks longer in `y3Axis`:

```
combinePlots[lp1, combinePlots[lp3, lp2, "AxesSides" -> "TwoY"], 
 "AxesSides" -> "TwoY", PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
 Epilog -> y3Axis /. {Orange -> Purple, 
   HoldPattern[TickLengths -> _] -> Rule[TickLengths, {5, 1}]},  
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Scaled[.18]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Comment: would it be possible to control the plot range for each plot independently, kindly see my updat

Comment: @valarmorghulis, please see update 2.

Comment: that is nice, thank you! why do ticks length on x axes are smaller compared to ones on y-axes?

Comment: that's because I did not touch the horizontal axes specs. Now added another layer of replacement to modify the horizontal axes.

Answer (score 9):

I just submitted an updated version of `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]` that supports more than two horizontal/vertical axes. It also fixes the issue with the squished plot markers.

**Update:** It has now been accepted, and is available simply as `ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"]`

Now, to your question:

```
dat1 = Table[{10.^i, Log[10.^i]}, {i, 1, 10}];
dat2 = Table[{10.^i, i Log[10.^i]}, {i, 1, 10}];
dat3 = Table[{10.^i, i Sin[i] Log[10.^i]}, {i, 1, 10}];   

ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat1, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 450, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y1"}, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}],
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat2, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y2"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}, 
  FrameStyle -> Darker@Green, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}],
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat3, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y3"}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}, FrameStyle -> Orange, 
  PlotStyle -> Orange, Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], "AxesSides" -> "MultiY"
 ]
```

[image]

Note the use of the new `"AxesSides"->"MultiY"`. Other than that, I only added the third plot to be combined with the others. If you'd rather have the third axis on the right, use `"AxesSides" -> {Left, Right, Right -> 2}`, or `"AxesSides"->{Left, {Right -> Automatic}}` if you want all additional plots to get their own axis on the right:

[image]

## Updated version

I have fixed the issue with the second axis on the right being shifted upwards, now it should work as expected:

```
ResourceFunction["CombinePlots"][
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat1, PlotRange -> {0, 30}, Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 450, FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y1"}, FrameStyle -> Blue, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, FontSize -> 16}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}],
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat2, PlotRange -> {0, 300}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y2"}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]},
   FrameStyle -> Darker@Green, PlotStyle -> Darker@Green, 
  Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}],
 ListLogLinearPlot[dat3, PlotRange -> {-200, 200}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"X", "Y3"}, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]},
   FrameStyle -> Orange, PlotStyle -> Orange, Joined -> True, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Scaled[0.03]}], 
 "AxesSides" -> {Left, Right, Right -> 2}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: that is great, however, adding  `PlotRange -> {0, 30}`  and  `PlotRange -> {0, 300}` and `PlotRange -> {-200, 200}` for dat123 respectively, shift the third axes and frame ticks at the edge are cut. see update

Comment: @valarmorghulis Thanks for catching this! I have fixed the underlying issue & resubmitted the new version (see the new section at the end). In the meantime, you can force-update by running the `ResourceRemove[...]` line followed by the `ResourceRegister[...]` line from the answer.

Comment: Sorry@Lukas Lang, I will accept kglr answer, it gives more freedom to control ticks length, label, and axes position.