# Rescaled tooltips

Tags: plotting, tooltip

Example data:

```
gdp = {{10, 2783}, {11, 2892}, {12, 2904}, {13, 2917}, {14, 2981}, {15, 3026}, 
{16, 3093}, {17, 3176}, {18, 3207}, {19, 3241.}, {20, 3121}, {21, 3203}, {22, 3261}};

pop = {{10, 34.1}, {11, 36.1}, {12, 36.2}, {13, 36.2}, {14, 36.9}, {15, 37.3}, 
{16, 37.6}, {17, 38.4}, {18, 38.7}, {19, 39.0}, {20, 37.5}, {21, 38.5}, {22, 39.2}};
```

I want to plot `pop` with a second right-sided axis. Since I couldn't find a solution with the `MultiaxisArrangement`-option (it doesnt't accept `Joined -> {True, False}` etc.), I used an answer found here:

[How to combine several plots with different $x$ and $y$-axis?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/285496/how-to-combine-several-plots-with-different-x-and-y-axis/285499#285499)

```
gdpm = MinMax @ gdp[[All, 2]];
popm = MinMax @ pop[[All, 2]];
popr = Transpose[{#1, Rescale[#2, popm, gdpm]} & @@ Transpose[pop]];
```

The plot looks like expected:

```
ListPlot[{gdp, popr},
 Filling -> {2 -> Axis},
 FillingStyle -> Thickness[0.04],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> {{All, Charting`FindTicks[gdpm, popm]}, {gdp[[All, 1]], None}},
 GridLines -> {All, Automatic},
 Joined -> {True, False},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.2, 0.5}, Automatic},
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[{2, 1}]]]
```

[image]

Unfortunately, the `Tooltip` of `popr` still shows the original values of `pop`. This can be easily fixed, I thought, write your own `Tooltip`:

```
 popt = Transpose[{pop, popr}] /. {{y_, rv_}, {_, ov_}} :> {y, Tooltip[ov, Row[{y, rv}, " - "]]}
```

But now, with `ListPlot[{gdp, popt}...`, `popt` doesn't show up at all!

How can I get rescaled `Tooltips`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
rescaleLabels = AssociationThread[
   Join[gdp[[All, -1]], Round @ popr[[All, -1]]], 
   Join[gdp[[All, -1]], pop[[All, -1]]]];

LF = Row[{#[[1]], ReplaceAll[Missing[_, a_] :> a] @ 
  rescaleLabels @ #[[2, 1]]}, ","] &;

ListPlot[{gdp, popr}, 
 PlotHighlighting -> {{"IndicatedPoint"}, 
     {"XYLabel", <|LabelingFunction -> LF|>}},
 Filling -> {2 -> Axis}, 
 FillingStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.04], CapForm["Butt"]], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{All, Charting`FindTicks[gdpm, popm]}, {gdp[[All, 1]],
     None}}, 
 GridLines -> {All, Automatic}, 
 Joined -> {True, False}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0.2, 0.5}, Automatic}, 
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[{2, 1}]]]
```

[image]

[image]